# MySQL - select a row using REGEXP within multiple columns if any word in query matchs

Tags: php, mysql, regex, database

I have three tables:

1. post
2. tags
3. past_tags

So, I want to make a simple search to get the post ID using it's title only, related tags only, and title and tag.

To explain my point take this example:

In post table I have columns named (post_id, post_title)

> Example: post_id: **1** - post_title: **my new super car**

In tags table I have columns named (tag_id, tag_name)

> Example: tag_id: **5** - tag_name: **red**

In post_tags I record the post_id of "post" and the tag_id of "tag":

> Example: post_id: **1** - tag_id: **5**

so each post can has many tags (a simple relationship).

I want to select the post post_id if I enter any of these queries:

1. supper car
2. **red** car
3. **red** super car
4. super **red** car
5. red

It's a kind of merging the results and match the post_id even if the query is not related to one column.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For "word" matching, learn about `FULLTEXT` indexing.  `REGEXP` is less practical.